# How do I disable system pop-ups in Windows CE 6?

Tags: popup, windows-ce, kiosk

What do I have to do to disable all system pop-ups in WinCE 6 R2?

I read Mike Hall's post about Kiosk mode [1] but that's not going to work for us because we still want the standard graphical Explorer shell.  We plan on hiding the taskbar and start menu and clearing icons off the desktop but need an easy way to make sure that no pop-ups of any type will ever show up on top of our app.

Thanks,
Ben

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehall/archive/2007/06/01/kiosk-mode-for-ce-6-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What pop ups are you referring to? Windows CE has no pop ups, unless something crashes of course and then you get a `MessageBox` with the error.